# Json file to sql table in ADF

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

Im trying to load a json file into a table in azure, the json file looks like this:

```json
{
  "Status": {
      "0": "Fictitious",
      "1": "To be checked",
      "2": "Created"
   },
  "TimePeriod": {
    "Year": "year",
    "Quarter": "quarter",
    "Month": "month",
    "Week": "week",
    "Day": "day"
  }
}
```

And i want to load it into an azure sql database table that have this structure:

[image]

[image]

I want to do this in ADF and i tried to use a dataflow where i unpivot the file but i can´t seem to find a way to unpivot it into rows and also get the "Status" as an own column.
I can´t find any examples where the json file have this structure, any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Can you edit the question to give complete json data for atleast one row (the sample given above is incomplete)

Comment: It is complete now, thanks.

Comment: Is this the exact format of the data, or can it be dynamic (number of status modes like 0,1,2 and so on)

Comment: This is the exact format of the data

Comment: What do you want to do with the Time period details?

Comment: Same as status, it goes in the same table, added a picture.

Comment: I have updated the solution to include both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can achieve this using derived column, select and unpivot transformations. The following is how the source data looks like (sample taken as given in the question).

[image]

- Use derived column transformation to create 4 new columns as shown in the below image:

[image]

- Use select transformation to get only the above created columns:

[image]

- Now in unpivot transformation, ungroup by `Mode` column, select unpivot key as `Status` and unpivoted columns as `definition`. This would give result as shown below:

[image]

- You can write this to the required sink azure SQL database table as per requirement. The following is the dataflow JSON (incomplete) for the above described steps:

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "derivedColumn1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "unpivot1"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          Status as ({0} as string, {1} as string, {2} as string),",
                "          TimePeriod as (Year as string, Quarter as string, Month as string, Week as string, Day as string)",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> source1",
                "source1 derive({0} = Status.{0},",
                "          {1} = Status.{1},",
                "          {2} = Status.{2},",
                "          Mode = 'Status') ~> derivedColumn1",
                "derivedColumn1 select(mapColumn(",
                "          Mode,",
                "          {0},",
                "          {1},",
                "          {2}",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 unpivot(output(",
                "          Status as string,",
                "          definition as string",
                "     ),",
                "     ungroupBy(Mode),",
                "     lateral: true,",
                "     ignoreNullPivots: false) ~> unpivot1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Updated Dataflow JSON to transform time period data as well (sinks are yet to be configured as per your requirement into SQL table):

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "status"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "unpivot1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "timeperiod"
                },
                {
                    "name": "select2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "unpivot2"
                }
            ],
            "scriptLines": [
                "source(output(",
                "          Status as ({0} as string, {1} as string, {2} as string),",
                "          TimePeriod as (Year as string, Quarter as string, Month as string, Week as string, Day as string)",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     ignoreNoFilesFound: false,",
                "     documentForm: 'singleDocument') ~> source1",
                "source1 derive({0} = Status.{0},",
                "          {1} = Status.{1},",
                "          {2} = Status.{2},",
                "          Mode = 'Status') ~> status",
                "status select(mapColumn(",
                "          Mode,",
                "          {0},",
                "          {1},",
                "          {2}",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select1",
                "select1 unpivot(output(",
                "          Status as string,",
                "          definition as string",
                "     ),",
                "     ungroupBy(Mode),",
                "     lateral: true,",
                "     ignoreNullPivots: false) ~> unpivot1",
                "source1 derive(Year = TimePeriod.Year,",
                "          Quarter = TimePeriod.Quarter,",
                "          Month = TimePeriod.Month,",
                "          Week = TimePeriod.Week,",
                "          Day = TimePeriod.Day,",
                "          name = 'TimePeriod') ~> timeperiod",
                "timeperiod select(mapColumn(",
                "          Year,",
                "          Quarter,",
                "          Month,",
                "          Week,",
                "          Day,",
                "          name",
                "     ),",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true) ~> select2",
                "select2 unpivot(output(",
                "          TimePeriod as string,",
                "          Value as string",
                "     ),",
                "     ungroupBy(name),",
                "     lateral: true,",
                "     ignoreNullPivots: false) ~> unpivot2"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```